# Form Validation separator

Tags: forms, validation

I would like to validate text entries in a google form comparing them with a string list in a spreadsheet
i was use my script but the result is use comma
either it's need '|' separator
any solution ?
i'm sorry for my bad english

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAcLq.jpg)

```
function NIMValidasi() {
  var
  id_form=FormApp.openById("1d18STE659dc0lnkjzNI7aAaEaJTvKZPL9ey5CBRhPo4");
    var id_nim=id_form.getItemById("1535638147").asTextItem();
    var
  sheet_data=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Mendaftar Anggota")
    var ambil_data=sheet_data.getRange(2,2,sheet_data.getLastRow()).getValues();

    var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
    .setHelpText("Maaf NIM Belum Terdaftar")

    .requireTextContainsPattern(ambil_data)
    .build();

    id_nim.setValidation(textValidation);
}

function onedit(){
  NIMValidasi();
}
```

i was search on google but i dont know